# Como guardo un archivo en la carpeta data de otra aplicacion?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Estoy desarrollando una applicacion la cual quiero que guarde un archivo '`xxname`' a la carpeta data de otra aplicacion, el archivo se guarda en la carpeta data de mi aplicacion pero como lo muevo de esa carpeta.

Ejemplo:
De: `var/mobile/containers/data/application/myApp/Documents`
A: `var/mobile/containers/data/application/OtherApp/Documents/bin`

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

con respecto a lo que te refieres, tengo entendido que no se puede, ya que Apple maneja un sandbox por cada aplicación y ninguna aplicación puede entrar al sandbox de una tercera, te anexo como se maneja lo del sandbox.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html

A lo mejor te refieres es a utilizar un ActivityViewController para guardar un archivo de tu app, en otra app o compartir.
De igual forma te dejo la documentación oficial.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller